# Event generated by a function call?

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to update a default value in a combobox, after a function is called successfully, how could i do that?

my basic idea is this.

```
if xfunc return True : widget.set(updated_value)
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be pseudocode or python because it's invalid syntax.

Comment: sorry just noticed the error, well basicaly if i get some how to know y the function has run successfuly i get to update the value of the widget

Comment: `if xfunc: widget.set(updated_value)`

Comment: that's correct, that's what i intended

Comment: how can i make some code like that, act like an event, without using a loop?

Comment: I literally gave you the code.

Comment: well, i guess i didn't make myself clear enough, the problem here is, that i have a widget that holds a list of values, the user inputs data on different entry fields, what i want is, that afther the user hits the "save" button, (witch is a function that grabs the data and store it's on a DB) one of the values saved, becomes a default value in the widget i mention.

Answer (score 0):

return is a keyword that is used to return objects during runtime in a function, meaning if you write the word 'return' anywhere in the function (main or otherwise): the compiler will try to end the function with whatever follows as the return type.  Therefore, when writing if statements: in your mind try to replace the function call 'xfunc()' with whatever you think it will return, and test to see if it is equal ('==') with the return you want ('True')

However, the job of a if-statement is to test if something is True. Therefore if xfunc() == True: would be redundant (*as pointed out by **all or None***), so we can simplify this statement to if xfunc():

ex:

```
if xfunc():
     #run success code here
```

Comment: Note that the `== True` is redundant.

Comment: Wow I don't even know how that didn't cross my mind, thank you